# Problems with Umbraco version 8.4.0 on Windows 2016 Standard Server

Tags: umbraco, windows-server-2016, umbraco8

I'm trying to install an Umbraco version 8.4.0 on Windows 2016 Standard Server. 
The dev machine is Windows 10 Pro on which the installation works fine.
But when I deploy to the Windows 2016 Standard Server the pages loaded do not format well - the footer, header and other compositions setup in the back-end do render.
There are no 500 server errors or Javascript errors in console. I'm clueless about whats going wrong?

Has anyone installed Umbraco v8 on windows 2016 server, are there any special considerations for installing it?

Please could someone help me, I'm really stuck on it and not sure how to go and resolve it.

Comment: Can you explain what exactly "do not format well"  means? CSS issue? Frontend or backend?

Comment: It was a back-end issue. I've added the answer.

Answer (score 0):

We gave "Network Service" permissions to modify the website folders. That fixed it, not sure though why because Umbraco was already running without the "Network services" in the permissions. It was only the new release of the website that got affected, the previous release had no issues without Network Services having these permissions.

If anyone get stuck with something like this should check the permissions for the website folders.